# Extract a value from the chart, filtered by criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup-tables

I've got two sheets like this in excel :

Price chart :

```
                            **Post AB**    **Post  Tenn**   **Post DN**
                         Price 10.1-10.20  Price 10.1-10.20  Price 10.1-20.1
CityOrigin  Destination      20 kg  40 kg    20 kg  40 kg     20 kg  40 kg

New York     Madrid          45      40     40      50       45      40
Los Angeles  Madrid          65      70     70      70       56      60
Oregon       Paris           89      100    110     105      74      98
Washington   Paris           34      80     45      65       45      69
```

and Working chart:

```
                                            Price Rate
Post Career  CityOrigin          Date            20KG      40KG
Post AB      New Tork          =Today()            ?        ?
Post Tenn    Los Angles            "               ?        ?
Post DN      Oregon                "               ?        ?
```

I am wondering, is it possible to use today date with Post Career and City origin to extract only rates that are actually valid for today for 20kg and 40kg packages from price chart sheet?

My ideal result should be look like this :

```
                                                   Price Rate
Post Career  CityOrigin          Date            20KG      40KG
Post AB      New York             10/20           40       45
Post Tenn    Los Angles           10/20           70       70
Post DN      Oregon               10/20           74       98
```

My question is which function I should use to call the price based on date and post career from price sheet? multiple Lookup??

Comment: Can you modify your table structure like the headers so it will be easier to do without all the checking?

Comment: The thing is I have got price chart which *Price 10.1-10.20* is only one cell. You mean I should breakdown the date cell into two?

Comment: Correct.  It will be easier to use in the formula so you don't need to parse that string to two dates and compare (that will make the formula too long).

Comment: Also, I am curious how the data is going to look like if you have more info for different date ranges.  If you can add that to the example that will help us to understand better.

Comment: I see your point. I donot have more info for different date range, only from 1st of October until today 20th October.

Comment: @ian0411 regarding your comment on my new post. You are right I had to focus on one and edit the question if you have more info. it's my bad! I got the complete data set and couldn't find a way around it with your recommendation I thought maybe I should ask a new question. My apologies. I can put this question on hold. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So here is what I have so far without knowing how other date ranges will be like in your data structure, but this should give you something to work on.

The formula I entered in `cell D13` is:

```
=INDEX($C$4:$H$7,MATCH($B13,$A$4:$A$7,0),MATCH($A13,$C$1:$H$1,0)+IF(D$12="20 kg",0,1))
```

Basically I just use `INDEX/MATCH` to lookup the row and column numbers.  Once you have other data come in to play, I can take another look if you can't find a way around it.

Please note that I have removed the `*` sign on row 1 so it is easier to do in the `MATCH` function, otherwise, you will need to use array formula to do this and that is probably not the way you want to go.