# Extract a value from the master sheet where the date is falls in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract, lookup-tables

I am struggling to solve this problem since morning. I would appreciate if you could give me a hint.

I have a master sheet containing price data range for different date periods :
[image]

Based on today date (10/20) I should refer to an appropriate date period columns (J&K) or (V&W) , extract valid date period & price rate for 20' & 40' and allocate them to my final sheet :

What is the best way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you change the dates in row 2 to 2 separate cells - One for the start date and one for the end date? The way it is now is a text field so it would be much harder to find out if your date fits between the 2.

Comment: It might be possible with worksheet formulas, but I would suggest you work on a VBA solution.

Comment: Did you just ask this similar question earlier (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847655/extract-a-value-from-the-chart-filtered-by-criteria-in-excel#comment80648258_46847655)?  You can focus on one and edit the question if you have more info.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a tricky one, but it's do-able.  (It would be way easier to do in Access instead of Excel.)

My 'tip' would be to break this down into smaller problems: split up the date ranges into 2 columns each, and then figure out how to [lookup a date in multiple date range columns](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=excel%20vlookup%20OR%20match%20%22date%20range%22%20OR%20%22date%20ranges%22%20in%20multiple%20columns%20OR%20rows&oq=excel%20vlookup%20OR%20match%20%22date%20range%22%20OR%20%22date%20ranges%22%20in%20multiple%20columns%20OR%20rows).  [This](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/603269-using-vlookup-lookup-date-within-multiple-date-ranges.html) and [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2702-excel-vlookup-between-date-range.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an array formula you can try:

```
=INDEX(
    data_array,
    MATCH($C3&$F3,pol&pod,0),
    MATCH(
        I$2&$E3&1,
        inches&OFFSET(ff,0,-(I$2="40'"))
            &(IFERROR(TODAY()>=DATEVALUE(LEFT(OFFSET(dates,0,-(I$2="40'")),FIND(" - ",OFFSET(dates,0,-(I$2="40'")))-1)),FALSE)
                *IFERROR(TODAY()<=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(OFFSET(dates,0,-(I$2="40'")),LEN(OFFSET(dates,0,-(I$2="40'")))-FIND(" - ",OFFSET(dates,0,-(I$2="40'")))-2)),FALSE)
            ),
        0
    )
)
```

**Note:** Paste this formula in cell I3 (which is where the data starts according to your screenshots) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I've used the following range names to make the formula more readable:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╗
║    Name    ║       Range        ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ data_array ║ =Master!$G$6:$T$10 ║
║ dates      ║ =Master!$H$2:$U$2  ║
║ ff         ║ =Master!$G$1:$T$1  ║
║ inches     ║ =Master!$G$5:$T$5  ║
║ pod        ║ =Master!$B$6:$B$10 ║
║ pol        ║ =Master!$A$6:$A$10 ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

I've taken a screenshot to help you understand the range names I've used:

[image: Range Names]

You can modify the names to suit your preferences, and alter the ranges according to your data.

**Note:**

- The size of `ff` and `dates` should be equal to the `inches` range. These three are used by the MATCH function that returns the `column_num` value in the outer INDEX function.
- Similarly, the vertical sizes of `data_array`, `pod` and `pol` should be the same.

Here's the Final sheet after entering the formula:

[image: Final sheet after entering the formula]

I've highlighted the relevant results from the Master sheet to show that the formula works.

*I'll add an explanation later when I get time.*